# Resolving Slurm cgroups Plugin Errors on Ubuntu 22.04 Nodes

Tags: ubuntu, slurm, cgroup

I'm working with [Slurm](https://slurm.schedmd.com/documentation.html) and [facing issues](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77574925/2371987) specifically with the cgroups plugin on [Ubuntu 22.04 nodes](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/762858/143352). Our team is relatively new to Slurm, and we've been trying to optimize our resource management for complex computing tasks. However, we've encountered a series of errors that are proving difficult to resolve.

Here's a brief overview of our problem:

- We initially used the cgroups V2 plugin on two Ubuntu 22.04 nodes and one Ubuntu 18.04 node, which didn't work as expected.
- After switching to the cgroups V1 plugin, we could run jobs on the Ubuntu 18.04 node, but the Ubuntu 22.04 nodes started showing errors.
- The errors include issues with opening and mounting directories in `/sys/fs/cgroup`, and the nodes go into `idle` and then `drain` states post job execution attempts.

As follows, are the logs where the errors start to appear:

```
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.479] [36.batch] error: unable to open '/sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset//tasks' for reading : No such file or directory
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.511] [36.batch] error: unable to mount cpuset cgroup namespace: Device or resource busy
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.511] [36.batch] error: unable to create cpuset cgroup namespace
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.511] [36.batch] error: unable to open '/sys/fs/cgroup/devices//tasks' for reading : No such file or directory
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.512] [36.batch] cgroup/v1: xcgroup_ns_create: cgroup namespace 'devices' is now mounted
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.514] [36.batch] error: common_cgroup_lock error
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.514] [36.batch] error: task_g_pre_setuid: task/cgroup: Unspecified error
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.514] [36.batch] error: Failed to invoke task plugins: one of task_p_pre_setuid functions returned error
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.515] [36.batch] error: called without a previous init. This shouldn't happen!
[2023-10-12T14:50:29.515] [36.batch] error: job_manager: exiting abnormally: Slurmd could not execve job
```

We've tried altering kernel parameters, but this hasn't resolved the issue. I'm looking for advice on troubleshooting these errors on Ubuntu 22.04.

**Any insights into potential causes or diagnostic tools that could be useful in this scenario?**

Comment: Have you asked our sexy brethren over at https://serverfault.com/?

Comment: Just curious: is there a particular reason for having nodes with different version of the OS on the same cluster? I guess one can separate these into different partitions, but keeping different versions of programs compiled for a two versions vs OS upgrade looks like  more work.